# Short caption in margin

Tags: captions, margins, marginpar, etoolbox

Is it possible to insert the short caption of a figure in the margin next to it?
I tried to get it working with `etoolbox` but without success. Additionally it has to work with the package `subcaption` loaded.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% maybe use
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, \marginpar{I want the short caption like this}
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{test}
\caption[Short Caption]{My Long Caption}
\end{figure}
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you not use `\caption[Short Caption]{My Long Caption\marginnote{Short caption}}`?

Comment: ``marginnote`` is fine, however I don't wanna repeat the short caption. Hence I tried to use ``etoolbox``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it automatically done for every `\caption`, you can add the following to your preamble:

```
\let\oldcaption\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[2][\empty]{%
    \ifx#1\empty%
        \oldcaption{#2}%
    \else%
        \oldcaption[#1]{\marginnote{#1}#2}%
    \fi}
```

If no short caption is given, nothing will happen. If a short caption is given, it will append a `\marginnote` to the caption, containing the short caption.

To avoid compatibility issues with the `caption` package, you can wrap it inside a `\caption@AtBeginDocument` like this:

```
\makeatletter
\caption@AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\oldcaption\caption
    \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\empty]{%
        \ifx#1\empty%
            \oldcaption{#2}%
        \else%
            \oldcaption[#1]{\marginnote{#1}#2}%
        \fi}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I think he would still want the short caption in the list of figures.

Comment: The short caption should be in the list of figures.

Comment: So it is.  One other thing, shouldn't the \marginote go before #2 in case the long caption is more than one line?

Comment: Thx, but I mentioned that it has to work with ``subcaption`` loaded. I tried your approach before and got ``! Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly``

Comment: @JohnKormylo Right, it is better. Thanks! @ManuelSchmidt I may not have an old version of the `caption` package, but see my updated answer. Hope it works for you (remember to compile at least twice so that the note position is correct).